# How does MediaExtractor determine what to put in H264 NAL units?

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I've examined the output of MediaExtractor on two Android devices, and it appears to produce slightly different samples on them, given the same 
video file.

With one device, non-VCL NAL units are concatenated onto the next VCL unit to
produce a sample. On the other device, each non-VCL unit constitutes a complete sample.

Another difference: On one device the samples have the leading 0 byte and start code prefix (001) in the sample; on the other, those bytes are omitted.

If I try to use the format of NAL units for the first device on the other device, the video does not play.

If I'm producing my own NAL units (not using MediaExtractor), is there a principled way to know what format the MediaCodec H264 decoder is expecting?

Comment: I should mention that I'm feeding these NAL units to a MediaCodec input buffer.

Comment: why not look at the source? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/600ca140e2e31e76f9bef7d484387ea366812cb3/media/java/android/media/MediaExtractor.java

Comment: A sample is what readSampleData produces. The Java source isn't much help, because it's calling native code which itself is calling some lower level code.

Answer (score 2):

The official way is to have the start code prefixes present (which are necessary for having multiple NAL units in one packet) - this is what all OpenMAX IL (the standard used internally below MediaCodec) decoders expect (even if some also may support other formats). Whether you have SPS/PPS in a separate buffer (with the `BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG` flag set) or prepended to a buffer with VCL NAL units shouldn't matter - decoders should be able to handle both I think. I don't think you'll find any individual document that clarifies this for Android though, other than implicitly deducing it from what devices actually do.

Can you name which devices (and which platform versions) output which combination of these bitstream variants, and which combination fails on which device? AFAIK a stream with startcodes present should work everywhere, but there may of course be exceptions. Since Android 4.3, these things should be much more well-behaved than they were on 4.1 and 4.2.

Some vendors do seem to do nonstandard things in MediaExtractor - I've written a bug report about this at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74356. In that case, the Samsung specific nonstandard behaviour is signaled with a `isDMCMMExtractor=1` key in the MediaFormat. I really agree that MediaExtractor should be stricter specified, because right now it's mostly only usable for feeding data into MediaCodec (where it is assumed to be understood, at least for the vendor specific HW codecs), but it's hard to say what it actually does, if an app would want to do something else with the MediaExtractor output (e.g. decode with a third party bundled decoder, or send the extracted data over the network, etc).

If some device fails to decode the de-facto standard bitstream format (but only succeeds if it is mangled the way that platform's MediaExtractor does it), it sounds like another CTS compatibility test is warranted, by testing decoding of raw, hardcoded packets (so that MediaExtractor can't get inbetween and transform things). Do CTS tests like EncodeDecodeTest (see http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) work properly on this device? If it does, but if decoding standard packet formats fail, it would mean that the device's encoder also outputs something nonstandard.

Comment: The device with the start code prefix and concatenated non-VCL units is a Nexus 7 2013 running Android 5.01. The device without the start code prefix and separate non-VCL units is a Huawei phone (sorry, don't have the model or Android version, someone else is testing it).

Comment: I haven't tried the CTS tests on these devices, yet.

Comment: What combination of bitstream did you test that didn't work? I'd guess that packets without start codes will fail on the Nexus 7, while packets with start codes probably should work on the Huawei.

Comment: That's right, packets without start codes fail on the Nexus.